# aligning textview to the center of actionbar

Tags: android

i want to align the title of my app to the center of my actionbar always.it must be responsive ie it must be aligned to center respective of the screen size.how can it be possible? i tried by creating layout folders and designing it for several screen sizes and adjust padding left and right for each screen sizes but it is not aligning to center.can anyone find me a solution??

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:shadowRadius="1"
android:text="Title"
android:textColor="#000010"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

javacode for actionbar

```
    View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mynewaction, null);
    final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 
    actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradientwhite));
```

also i have created folders layout-sw320dp,layout-sw480dp,layout-sw600dp,layout-sw720dp

this is the screenshot i get

[image]

Comment: remove paddingLeft  it disturb the text

Comment: remove android:paddingleft="89dp" and you will be fine .... :)(

Comment: replace your textview with this <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:shadowColor="@android:color/black" android:shadowRadius="1" android:text="Title" android:textColor="#000010" android:textSize="20sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: i tried it but the text now appears on top left corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#000010"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this. Hope it helps.

Comment: You are doing custom action bar right. Show how's its looking

Comment: see the edited question above @vo12..but it showing correct in graphical layout..

Comment: @Thusharaprasad check this http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Answer (score 1):

**Try to replace this all properties :**

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="89dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
```

**With only this properties :**

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

**Updated code :**

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView,params);
```

Comment: i tried this but its showing the text on left corner of action bar..see the image above

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center|top">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="89dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#000010"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```